# R: convert scalar vectors into one vector

Tags: r

I've got this code:

```
n<-5

for (i in 1:n) {
    for (k in 1:n) {
        print (i-k)
    }
}
```

So, results are scalar vectors. But I need to get one vector with all results in it, like this:

```
[1] 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 1 0 -1 -2
```

etc.
How can i get it? Trying `unlist()`, but no success.

Comment: How did you try unlist? `unlist(lapply(1:n, "-", 1:n))` is an option

Comment: I'm not sure i'm trying it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this vectorized:

```
n <- 5
as.vector(t(outer(1:n,1:n,'-')))
#[1]  0 -1 -2 -3 -4  1  0 -1 -2 -3  2  1  0 -1 -2  3  2  1  0 -1  4  3  2  1  0
```

OR

```
as.vector(sapply(1:n, function(i) i-(1:n)))
```

OR

```
as.vector(sapply(1:n,'-',1:n))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? Your result would be `a`...

```
n <- 5 
a <- c()
for(i in 1:n) { 
  for(k in 1:n) { 
    print (i-k) 
    a <- c(a, i-k)
  } 
}
```

Comment: But the result is the same as mine. I need result like in first comment.